# Retrieving data from checkbox - php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `Choice` list contain 4 types of Articles. The user should take one choice. Now the list become contain 45 Articles and I changed the `choice list` by a `checkBox list`for multiple choices.

This following the old `setter` function:

```
 public function setNature($nature) {
        $this->_nature = $nature;
        if ($nature === 'Production') { $this->_nature='Production';   }
        elseif ($nature === 'A'){ $this->_nature='A';}
        elseif ($nature === 'B') {$this->_nature='B';}
        else $this->_nature ='all';
    }
```

How I can change this setter function to recovre the data without write all the 45 types of articles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate the looking for allowed natures like so:

```
public function setNature($nature) {
    $allowed_nature = ['A','B','Production'];
    if(in_array($nature, $allowed_nature)){
        $this->_nature = $nature;
    }else{
        $this->_nature = 'all';
    }
}
```

The only negative side is that you need to store the allowed natures somewhere, in this case that would be an array, but it could be from your database as well.

Based on your current information, this is what I can make of it!

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. Yes effectively the 45 article are stored in the table in my database.

Comment: if you retrieve them, you can set them in an array, so that you never have to update it again, just use a comma separated list of natures, and this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'> <tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3
    </td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' class='buttons'> </form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvar'])) 
{
    print_r($_POST['checkboxvar']); 
}
?>
```

Hope this Helps

```
echo implode(',', $_POST['checkboxvar']); // change the comma to whatever separator you want
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would prevent him from editing the setter to have over 45 elseif's ?

Comment: you are right, sorry i didn't understood the question

Comment: No Problem, but this might help OP get all the names once to put in an array or something :)